# Trouble building an ActiveModel in Ruby on Rails 3 using namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to build an ActiveModel [this way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb):

```
module Users # I use a namespace
  class Account
    extend ActiveModel::Naming
    extend ActiveModel::Translation
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :name
    attr_reader :errors

    def initialize
      @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
    end

    def validate!
      errors.add(:name, "can not be nil") if name == nil
    end

    # The following methods are needed to be minimally implemented

    def read_attribute_for_validation(attr)
      send(attr)
    end

    def Account.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
      attr
    end

    def Account.lookup_ancestors
      [self]
    end


    def persisted?
      false
    end
end
```

If in my controller I make this

```
def create
  @account = Users::Account.new
  @account.errors.add( :name, "can not be blank" )
  ...
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `add' for nil:NilClass
```

If I make

```
@new_account = Users::Account.new
```

the debug of `@new_account` is

```
--- !ruby/object:Users::Account 
id: 
name: 
surname: 
updated_at:
```

**Where is the error and how can I solve that?**

---

P.S.: I don't want to use `validate_presence_of` because I need a different validation process, but I think that also that method doesn't work.

---

If I use the `validate!` method I get the following error that refers to that

```
NoMethodError in Users/accountsController#create

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=

Application trace
pp/models/users/account.rb:16:in `validate!'
```

Comment: Last time I checked namespaced models don't play nice. Is there a particular reason you _must_ have them be namespaced?

Comment: Yes, I need namespace in order to organize files in my application.

Comment: Andrew, what specifically do you think doesn't work with namespaced models?

Comment: We use namespaced models all the time, no problems here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ActiveModel::Validations automatically defines errors for you. You are probably overwriting this when you define

```
attr_reader :errors
```

Comment: Indeed, if you remove the `attr_reader` and the initialisation of the `@errors`, it will just work.